# App script onEvent api call updating cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To start Ive been trying to get this accomplished on my ow but finally I decided I need to ask for help. What I am trying to accomplish is. spreadedsheet contains info on vehicles that are being traded in. Each row contains a vehicle. When a vin gets entered into a cell in the E column the script sends an api call to nhtsa to decode the year, make and model. My script needs expanded but currently it reads contents of the cell containing the vin, makes the api call and returns the correct info into sheet.
What I cant figure out is how to include onEdit in my script to run a api query every time a new vin gets entered into the cell E1..  Then I would need to expand that to run everytime a new vin gets enetered into column E then return the values to the same rom in column B , C and D.

If someone could please give a little help I would greatly appreciate it.

here is the code

```
function onEdit(e){


   var sheet = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('VINDECODEAPI');
   var vin = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue();
   Logger.log
   Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());

//function to call api and get vin make
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/" +vin+ "?format=json");
// parse the reply
   var json = response.getContentText();
   var data = JSON.parse(json);
   Logger.log(data["Results"][0]["ModelYear"]);
   Logger.log(data["Results"][0]["Make"]);
   Logger.log(data["Results"][0]["Model"]);
// set name for returned data
   var year = (data["Results"][0]["ModelYear"]);
   var make = (data["Results"][0]["Make"]);
   var model = (data["Results"][0]["Model"]);
// print returned data to sheet
    sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue([year]);
    sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue([make]);
    sheet.getRange(1,4).setValue([model]);
```

}

Comment: I hope you realize that onEdit() trigger only fires on user edits not on changes performed by formulas or orther scripts...only user edits.

Comment: I might also guess that you might need to be using an installable onEdit() to be using urlFetchApp();

Answer (score 0):

I simplified it a bit for you.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('VINDECODEAPI');
  const vin = sh.getRange(1, 5).getValue();
  const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVinValues/" + vin + "?format=json");
  const data = JSON.parse(r.getContentText());
  const year = (data["Results"][0]["ModelYear"]);
  const make = (data["Results"][0]["Make"]);
  const model = (data["Results"][0]["Model"]);
  sh.getRange(1, 2 ,1, 3).setValues([year,make,model]);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it!!!!  After hitting the road block and doing some research I found that writing the script as a custom function would end up being the best route.